# Exportar arreglo que viene de una función asíncrona

Tags: javascript, nodejs, async

Amigos, tengo el siguiente problema quiero exportar un array, si se fijan lo declaro en la parte superior del archivo. Obvio esto no funciona, ya que la llamada a sheets.spreadsheets.values.get es asícrona. Entonces siempre exportaré un arreglo vacío.

¿Cómo podría exportar ese array?

Quiero que otro archivo lo pueda consumir. Sólo que tengo el problema con las llamadas asíncronas.

Si pudieran guiarme se los agradecería muchísimo.

Gracias

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis')

const { categories, sheetsConfig } = require('./utils')
const keys = require('./credentials.json')

let resource = []

const client = new google.auth.JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
)

client.authorize((error, tokens) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error)
    }

    getValues(client)
})

const getValues = (auth) => {
    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth })
    let id = 1

    categories.map(categoryName => {
        sheetsConfig.range = `${categoryName}!A2:G`
    
        sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(sheetsConfig, (error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error)
            }
    
            let rows = response.data.values
    
            if (rows.length) {
                rows.map(row => {

                    let newQuestion = {
                        id: id,
                        category: row[1],
                        question: row[2],
                        curiosity: row[4],
                        answers: [
                            {
                                value: row[3],
                                correct: true
                            },
                            {
                                value: row[5],
                                correct: false
                            },
                            {
                                value: row[6],
                                correct: false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    
                    id++
                    resource.push(newQuestion)
                })
            }

            console.log(resource)
        })  
    })
}

exports.jsonData = resource
```

Comment: Hola, deberías exportar una función asíncrona que devuelva tu valor, luego desde donde la consumes debes implementar el procedimiento para capturar el valor de forma asíncrona y trabajar con el mismo. Es lo que @EduardoMoreno intentó explicarte. Saludos

Answer (score -3):

Puedes hacer uso de promesas o de async await para esperar a que llegue la data y  así poder trabajar con la información.
Puedes intentar con lo siguiente

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')

const { categories, sheetsConfig } = require('./utils')
const keys = require('./credentials.json')

let resource = []

const client = new google.auth.JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
);
autorizarClientes =() =>{

    client.authorize(async (error, tokens) => {
      if (error) {
          return console.log(error)
      }

      return getValues(client)
  })
}

 const getValues = async (auth) => {
    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth })
    let id = 1

    categories.map( categoryName => {
        sheetsConfig.range = `${categoryName}!A2:G`

       await  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(sheetsConfig, (error, response) => {
           let resource = [];
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error)
            }

            let rows = response.data.values

            if (rows.length) {
                rows.map(row => {

                    let newQuestion = {
                        id: id,
                        category: row[1],
                        question: row[2],
                        curiosity: row[4],
                        answers: [
                            {
                                value: row[3],
                                correct: true
                            },
                            {
                                value: row[5],
                                correct: false
                            },
                            {
                                value: row[6],
                                correct: false
                            }
                        ]
                    }

                    id++
                  resource.push(newQuestion)
                })
            }

            console.log(resource)
            return resource;
        })  
    })
}

exports.jsonData = autorizarClientes();
```

Comment: Si pudieras mostrar el camino amigo

Comment: algo que me doy cuenta es que estás usando let para resource y no var, eso puede causar conflico por el scope de la variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51233678/11156015 checa este post, en vez de mandar resource implícitamente en exports, puedes hacer un return de resource, y `let resoucre =[]` la crearías dentro de getValues()